# Unable to Render HDRI in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

The HDRI showed up fine in the preview, but didn't show up in the final cycles render. The transparent checkbox is disabled. The HDRI of the other window in the room (not shown) showed up accurately, both in the render and the preview. Both windows used the same glass texture.

How does this happen? What should I do? Thank you.[image]

Environmental Texture: [image]
Glass Texture for Window: [image]

Comment: Did you use an object to cut a hole in the wall for the window?

Comment: Yes, I used a cylinder to boolean the wall. Is this whats causing this issue?

Comment: If you didn't delete it and you're just hiding it then it's not showing in the preview (so your glass works fine) but it does show in the rendered result (so it blocks the view and you just have a glass on a hard non-transparent surface)

Comment: @Kyriakh, it turns out that I had a duplicate of the circle glass for testing out different textures and forgot it was still there. Thank you for putting this out.

Comment: @brockmann, thank you for sharing the post. Although its not the case for me, the post will most definitely save me in my future projects. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! More times than not, a forgotten item is what's messing up windows...